# java.net, hanging in java

Tags: java, networking

I can't seem to figure out why my httpurlconnection is hanging.

I have the following setup: connect url, check if response code is 200, if not sleep for 1 second, call httpurlconnection.disconnect(), and then try again, if 6 seconds pass, stop trying and return. if theres a 200 response code then try reading input stream with a bufferedreader, using `(if String (i =readLine())!=null`, setting the read timeout to 8 seconds.

All this is done using threads, and sometimes it hangs and other times it doesn't, so I tested it with a `Callable` and `executorservice`, so I could terminate after it doesn't return the inputstream after 30 seconds. But if there's a `timeoutexception`, from the executor service, the finally blocks for closing a `bufferedreader` don't get executed, and something still hangs. There is no infinite loop, and the code, given the 8 second read timeout of the `httpurlconnection` and 6 second limit to getting the 200 response should never go longer than 14-15 seconds but it often does.

So is there any case where a variable set to `httpurlconnection`, will not correctly terminate a stream with a call to `disconnect()?` Also, the javadoc for `urlconnection`'s `setReadTimeout` method states: "Some non-standard implementation of this method ignores the specified timeout. " What does this mean?

Comment: Holy wall of text batman. Try formatting this a bit nicer and most importantly, show your code.

Comment: Much words in only one paragraph!

Comment: What part of 'ignore' don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following setup: connect url, check if response code is
>   200, if not sleep for 1 second, call httpurlconnection.disconnect(),
>   and then try again, if 6 seconds pass, stop trying and return. if
>   theres a 200 response code then try reading input stream with a
>   bufferedreader, using (if String (i =readLine())!=null, setting the
>   read timeout to 8 seconds.

Throw it all away and use URLConnection.setReadTimeout(). That's what it's for. As you are using HTTP, you are getting a 'standard implementation' so you don't have to worry about the 'ignore' part. Apparently you haven't even tried it or you would already know that.

Answer (score -1):

Ouch, that seems like a needlessly complex solution. Why not use the Java HTTPCLient from apache? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: What seems like a needlessly complex solution?

Comment: The OP looks like they are trying to communicate with a roll-your-own http client. I was pointing out that there are far simpler ways to do this.